# admin panel url not working after installing magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, installation

i have installed theme based on magento 2.2.5 storefront looks good but admin panel is showing this error:

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.0.30
```

I tried to download the xdebug and add this `zend_extension = "C:\newxampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.0alpha1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll"` to the bottom of the php.ini file but url showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy .htaccess file from Pub folder to root.